# How to calculate the SUM for business document with errors?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I am trying to Calculate the SUM of cells G11 through G49. Excluding cells G21 through 23 because they generate "#Value" Error due to certain criteria of other columns/cells.

I have tried pretty much everything I could find on MS office support, google searching and youtube

Here is a copy of the file in reference WITH comments included  on the cells providing issues.

https://easyupload.io/gzkdas

```
pw: association
```

Comment: Use `SUMIF` > `=SUMIF(G11:G49,"<>#Value")`

Comment: It returned the following error code: Err:508

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `range = G11:G49`, so you can use these ways:

1. ignore the error

   =AGGREGATE(9,6,G11:G49)                                         '  9=Sum & 6=ignore error
   =SUMIF(G11:G49,">0")+SUMIF(G11:G49,"<0")
2. By region

`=SUM(IFERROR(G11:G49,0)*((ROW(G11:G49)<21)+(ROW(G11:G49)>23)))  ' Ctrl + shift + enter`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25087651)

Comment: hi, why not? This will ignore all #Error #NA # DIVIDE0 errors!.

Comment: Suggesting someone to "try this" indicates it is just a guess on your part. In addition, high quality answers will also provide an explanation, not just a piece of code to 'try'.

Answer (score 0):

Select a blank cell, C3 for instance, and type this formula

```
=SUMIF(A1:A14,"<>#N/A")
```

press Enter key to get the result.
Give your selected area instead of A1:A14 and try.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing your function has error or no value so it returns #Value.

Try placing iferror(value.if.no.error, if.error)
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-C526FD07-CAEB-47B8-8BB6-63F3E417F611

example iferror( SUM(A1-A10), 0) in the field will place value of sum but if its an error, returns 0.